# How to address multicolinearity caused by large number of zeros in the predictors?

Tags: econometrics, multicollinearity

this is the first time I am posting a question here, so please forgive me if it  is out of place.

Basically I am trying to predict user behavior in an online forum. My main predictor is their topic of interest (x1). Two of the other predictors are their past history of activities in the forum: The number of threads they started(x2), and the number of replies they got(x3). And there are a bunch of other factors which I will not go into painful details here.

However, as you can imagine, many new users have zero in both, which accounts for over half of the entire data. As a result, the correlation between these two predictors is over the roof at 0.92. If I drop all users with zeros in both, the correlation drops to 0.21.

So the question is how do I include both predictors in the model, without losing too many sample and power, and not cause multicolinearity problem? Thanks a lot!

Comment: If your goal is prediction, then the strong correlation is not too much of a problem. This issue generally becomes important when you would like to interpret the resulting coefficients in the model, i.e., when you are interested in statistical inference.

Comment: You lose power by *not* including one of the predictors, assuming it gives any additional information about the behavior.